# How to convert a Boolean expression from POS form to SOP form?

Tags: digital-logic, design, boolean-algebra

[image]

POS equation is given as F=pi(3,8,12).
By converting POS to SOP form directly I get F=sigma(0,1,2,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,13,14,15)
But according to the process given in the above picture F is given as F=sigma(0,1,2,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,13,14,15)

Now, I'm confused as to which one of these equations are correct?
Or does it depend on the implementation technique? Like Kmap and others

This SOP conversion is for implementing Boolean expressions using Multiplexer. Does the equation change if it is implemented for Multiplexer?

Comment: We don't hand out homework solutions here. We expect you to show all of your work and ask a specific question. Explain exactly how you came up with your equation for F. When you derived F, did you consider the implementation method or not?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I'm not asking for a solution here. I just wanted to clarify if the above method for converting POS to SOP is correct?

Comment: What "method"? You haven't shown us any method. That's my point. Show us your method.

Comment: Converting F=pi(3,8,12) to F=sigma(0,1,2,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,13,14,15) using DeMorgan's theorem twice as shown in the above pic.

Comment: Do you think it is incorrect? If so, show us your work. I'm not going to slog through the Boolean algebra unless you show us your work first.

Comment: I'm just asking if the expression given in pic F=sigma(0,1,2,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,13,14,15) is right? Or my equation F=sigma(0,1,2,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,13,14,15) is right?

Comment: The book is wrong.